# php/mysql transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, insert, phpmyadmin

I'm doing a transaction with PHP and MySQL. Using PHPMyAdmin I'm inserting queries into my University DB, where I'm supposed to use transactions in some tables. So far I've made this code for my Staff transactions, but my problem is how can I get the information inserted in addStaff.php so I can use it as a query on this code? right where it says `//values();`

```
<?php
function begin() 
{
  mysql_query("BEGIN");
}
function commit()
{
  mysql_query("COMMIT");
}
function rollback()
{
  mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}

mysql_connect("localhost","username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT INTO Staff (id,name,position,phone,email,roomNumber,dnumber)"
//values();

begin(); // BEGIN
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
{
  rollback(); // ROLLBACK
  echo "You rolled back";
  exit;
}
else 
{
  commit(); // COMMIT
  echo "Transaction was succesful";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please stop using those prefixed `@`s before your code, that will give you way better error descriptions. Moreover, you miss a closing `"` after `dnumber)`

Comment: What do you mean by values inserted into addStaff.php? Do you mean from a submitted form? If so use `$_POST['input_name]` or `$_GET['input_name']` depending on the form's method attribute.

Comment: Just want to say: Make sure you're using INNODB MySQL tables.  You can't do real transactions on MyISAM tables which are sometimes default on phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correct, you need to know how to prompt for data, accept it, and insert it into the database:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

       ... connect to the database ...

       $sometext = $_POST['textfield']; // retrieve the value from the form

       $qsometext = mysql_real_escape_string($sometext); // make it safe for the query

       $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (textfield) VALUES ($qsometext);" // build the sql query

       $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); // run the query

    }
?>

<html>

<body>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="textfield"><input type="submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

That's a barebones version of how to show a form, then insert the user's data into a database, the simply re-displays the form for more data.

Comment: Shouldn't you use single quotes around `$qsometext`?

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe what you're looking for:

```
$new_row = mysql_insert_id();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Staff` WHERE `id`=".$new_row);
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

echo $r['name'];
```

will echo the inserted rows name.

**Edit:** This is a very very basic version of how to do things, before moving anything to production you need to read up on SQL Injection, Prepared Statements/Escaping User Input, XSS Attacks and many more vital parts of SQL query security

Comment: Be aware that you need to use `htmlspecialchars` to properly encode output to an HTML page (to prevent XSS).

Comment: I think given the question there are many many things that the OP needs to be aware of and have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Good addition: security should be part of the building from the beginning, not as an afterthought.